# Listview desparejo en c#

Tags: c#, listview

Estoy llenando un listview desde un select a la base de datos Oracle. Este es el codigo.

```
                //comado que establece un adaptador entre la base de datos y el programa
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // El tipo o el miembro están obsoletos
            OracleDataAdapter adaptador = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from ENCABEZADO_PRODUCTOS", cnn);
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // El tipo o el miembro están obsoletos
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

            adaptador.Fill(ds);//se llena el dataset
            tabla = ds.Tables[0];//se llena la tabla
            this.listView1.Items.Clear();//se limpa el list view
            ListViewItem item;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow filas = tabla.Rows[i];
                item = listView1.Items.Add(filas["ID_ORDEN"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["PROVEEDOR"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["TIPO_TRANSACCION"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["TIPO_COMPRA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["FECHA_EMISION"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["ESTADO"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["NUMERO_CUENTA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["MONEDA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["ID_PRODUCTO"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["ARTICULO"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["CATEGORIA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["UNIDAD_MEDIDA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["CANTIDAD_PEDIDA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["CANTIDAD_RECIBIDA"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["BACKORDER"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["COSTO_UNITARIO"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(filas["MONTO_TOTAL"].ToString());
            }
            cnn.Close();//se cierra la conexion
```

Que me presenta este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora... lo que yo necesito es que se vea algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]}
}

Seria agrupar las ordenes con el mismo id.

El select a la base de datos es una vista que seria esta:

```
SELECT
    O.ID_ORDEN,
    O.FECHA_EMISION,
    O.TIPO_TRANSACCION,
    O.TIPO_COMPRA,
    P.NOMBRE NOMBRE_PERSONA,
    D.ID_DETALLE,
    D.CANTIDAD_PEDIDA,
    D.CANTIDAD_RECIBIDA,
    D.BACKORDER,
    D.MONTO_TOTAL, 
    PROD.NOMBRE NOMBRE_PRODUCTO
FROM
    ORDEN         O,
    DETALLE       D,
    PERSONA       P,
    PERSONA_X_ROL PROL,
    PRODUCTO      PROD 
WHERE
    O.ID_DETALLE         = D.ID_DETALLE        AND
    P.ID_PERSONA         = PROL.PERSONA_ROL    AND
    O.PROVEEDOR_ORDEN_ID = PROL.ID_PERSONA_ROL AND
    D.PRODUCTO_ID        = PROD.ID_PRODUCTO;
```

Comment: Creo que subiste una imagen de ejemplo que no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta

Comment: y esto es winform o wpf? como es la vista?

Comment: @gbianchi es un Form

Comment: Pero vos queres arreglar la vista o el query? porque veo mucho sobre el query, y no me parece que tengas que tratar de arreglar el query (sobre todo, porque es un problema de vista segun lo que decis)

Comment: Honestamente yo tampoco creo que deba de arreglar el query, solamente que no se como mostrar en el listview de forma que la orden 1 se muestre una de esta manera... disculpa si no me doy a entender.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJaRP.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu consulta viene ordenada como vos queres, o sea que los registros estan como corresponde, lo que deberias hacer seria algo asi:

```
int ID_ORDEN = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow filas = tabla.Rows[i];
    if (filas["ID_ORDEN"] != ID_ORDEN )
    {
        ID_ORDEN = filas["ID_ORDEN"];
        item = listView1.Items.Add(filas["ID_ORDEN"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(filas["PROVEEDOR"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(filas["TIPO_TRANSACCION"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(filas["TIPO_COMPRA"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(filas["FECHA_EMISION"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        item = listView1.Items.Add("");
        item.SubItems.Add("");
        item.SubItems.Add("");
        item.SubItems.Add("");
        item.SubItems.Add("");
    }
    item.SubItems.Add(filas["ESTADO"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(filas["NUMERO_CUENTA"].ToString());
    ....
}
```

Lo que estamos haciendo aca, es comparando el orden con el anterior. Si el orden es otro, metemos todos los datos que queremos en la lista.. Si no, dejamos esas columnas en blanco, y solo llenamos las otras.

De esta forma vas a lograr lo que necesitas. Fijate que si los ordenes son diferentes, cambio el orden actual. Y empiezo el primero en 0.

Esto se conoce comunmente como cortes de control.